# Battery temperature in KitKat

Tags: android, battery

Has anybody tried getting the Battery temperature in KitKat?

For me, this part of code:

```
        int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(
                BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
```

works well and I get the correct temperature in Jellybean but not in KitKat.

Is there any other procedure to get the battery temperature in KK?

Thanks,
Uday

Answer (score 0):

Google revokes access to battery status information API in android 4.4. You can find more information here (http://androidnews.co.in/2013/11/27/google-revokes-access-battery-stats-api-android-4-4-kitkat-causing-battery-stats-app-stop-working/)